# Cannot get overflow text in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

```
 Widget commonText(
        {required String text, double? size, FontWeight? fontWeight, Color? color}) {
      return Text(text,
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: size,
          color: color ?? const Color(0xFF828282),
          fontWeight: fontWeight ?? FontWeight.bold,
          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis
      ),);
```

> I use it with listTitile wrap it with row

[image: This is what I get]

> this is first row i create

```
Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    Expanded(
      child: ListTile(
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          dense: true,
          horizontalTitleGap: 4,
          minVerticalPadding: 0,
          leading: CircleAvatar(
            radius: 17,
            backgroundImage: NetworkImage(userImage ??
                ("https://cambodiaict.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/computer-icons-user-profile-google-account-photos-icon-account.jpg")),
          ),
          title: Text(firstName.toString() + " " + lastName.toString(),
            style: const TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                color: Colors.black,
                fontSize: 16,
                letterSpacing: 0.1

            ),),
```

> i use row to wrap text and icons inside

```
          subtitle: Row(
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 2.0),
                    child: ImageIcon(
                        AssetImage(
                          'assets/images/hashtag.png',
                        ),
                        size: 12,
                        color: Color(0xFF828282)),
                  ),
                  commonText(text: uRoomNumber.toString(), size: 12),

                ],
              ),
              const SizedBox(width: 10,),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 2.0),
                    child: const ImageIcon(
                        AssetImage('assets/images/location.png'),
                        size: 12, color: Color(0xFF828282)),
                  ),
                  commonText(text: uLocation.toString(), size: 12),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          )
      ),
    ),
```

> this is the problem i want it to not overflowing

```
    Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16, right: 16),
      child: ExtendedText(
        "#" + userNumber.toString().toUpperCase(),
        style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 14,
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            fontFamily: 'quicksand_bold',
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
            color: AppColor.inactiveText
        ),
        maxLines: 1,
        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
        overflowWidget: const TextOverflowWidget(
          child: Text("...",
            style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
              color: Colors.black,
              fontSize: 16,
            ),
          ),
          position: TextOverflowPosition.start,

        ),
      ),
    )
  ],
);
```

> This what i have tried so far to not make text overflowing each other, i use row {list title sub title,} with container and inside container is another text. inside subtitle is text and icons.

Comment: Try wrapping your text inside Flexible

Comment: that would be hashsize, because i use list title and another text, wrap it with row

Comment: wrap the parent of this widget with a flexible widget

Comment: i have tried, not working!

Comment: Can you include an image what are you trying to archive,

Comment: I already did! thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your inner Row with `Expanded` and commonText `Text` with `Flexible` widget

```dart
Widget commonText(
  {required String text,
  double? size,
  FontWeight? fontWeight,
  Color? color}) {
return Flexible(
  child: Text(
    text,
    style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: size,
        color: color ?? const Color(0xFF828282),
        fontWeight: fontWeight ?? FontWeight.bold,
        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
  ),
);
}
```

And

```dart
subtitle: Row(
children: [
  Expanded(
    child: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
      ...
        commonText(...),
      ],
    ),
  ),
  const SizedBox(
    width: 10,
  ),
  Expanded(
    child: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        /...
        commonText(...),
      ],
    ),
  ),
],
)),
```

Comment: thank you this is working well! i just need a little align and all good

Comment: Glad to help you out, you can check more [Row](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Row-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

For the tile you are making i would suggest you to use `ListTile`

```
ListTile(
  leading: //image,
  title: //rothe chan,
  subtitle: Row(
    children: [
      //icon, 
      Expanded(child: //61dd...),
    ]
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>           Row( 
>           children:<Widget>[   
>
>            CircleAvatar( 
>            radius: 17,
>            backgroundImage: NetworkImage(url)),
>
>            Expaned(
>            child: Text(firstName.toString() + " " + 
>              lastName.toString(),
>              style: const TextStyle(
>              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
>              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
>              color: Colors.black,
>              fontSize: 16,
>              letterSpacing: 0.1
>          ),),)   ] );
> ```